# How do I enable High Replication Datastore on local dev_appserver?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I am using latest Java SDK 1.7.4, and the following command to start dev server:

```
%java.home%\bin\java -Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=20 -cp "%~dp0\..\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar" ^
    com.google.appengine.tools.KickStart ^
       com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain %*
```

( "datastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=20" as in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Using_the_Datastore )

Yet, log says on a first request to Datastore:

```
INFO: Local Datastore initialized:
        Type: Master/Slave
```

Then, I get an exception:

```
31.01.2013 19:16:02 org.datanucleus.transaction.Transaction rollback
SEVERE: Operation rollback failed on resource: org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreXAResource@404eb2, error code UNKNOWN and transaction: [DataNucleus Transaction, ID=Xid=    , enlisted resources=[org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreXAResource@404eb2]]
31.01.2013 19:16:02 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /themepark/post
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: transactions on multiple entity groups only allowed in High Replication applications
```

I have following lines in `\META-INF\jdoconfig.xml` to enable cross-group (XG) transaction:

```
<property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
<property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true"/>
```

How do I make `dev_appserver.cmd` emulate High Replication Datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Use the dev_appserver.cmd provided to pass in the argument and run your code as follows:

`dev_appserver --jvm_flag=-Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=20 <path_to_war_dir>`

You can try to include `--jvm_flag=-Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=20` to the end of your `dev_appserver.cmd` file if you'd like (right before the `%*`)

**OLD:**

Add the following to your command line:

`-Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=20`

It's one of the first things covered here (as well as other methods you can use): https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Using_the_Datastore

Comment: I already use this option. It is mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry I missed that

Comment: Hmm. I don't really understand why/how `com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain` ignores system property set with -D option, but the `--jvm_flag=-Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=20` option, being passed as an argument to the `com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain` class, do the trick, and run dev server in HR mode. Google's documentation is very unclear on the matter. 

Thank you!

Comment: So the right command is:

%java.home%\bin\java -cp "%~dp0\..\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar" ^
    com.google.appengine.tools.KickStart ^
       com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain --jvm_flag=-Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=20 %*